# Formating Using AWK to output reverse date and time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Let's say i have a line in the format of "YYYY-MM-DD-HH:MM:SS", how do i change it to "DD-MM-YYY HH:MM" ?

I've only managed to come up with this : `awk -F'-' '{ YY=$1 ; MM=$2 ; DD=$3  ; print DD MM YY  }'` which would output DDMMYYY .

Comment: `DD-MM-YYY` ? Not `DD-MM-YYYY` ?

Answer (score 2):

plain bash:

```
input="YYYY-MM-DD-HH:MM:SS"

IFS=": -" read y m1 d h m2 s <<<"$input"
output="$d-$m1-$y $h:$m2"
```

calling awk from shell:

```
input="YYYY-MM-DD-HH:MM:SS"
output=(
    echo "$input" | awk '
        split($0,a,/[: -]/) {
            printf "%s-%s-%s %s:%s\n", a[3],a[2],a[1],a[4],a[5]
        }
    '
)
```

Both assume input is well-formed.

---

Notes:

- I initially had a space between DD and HH because I misread your question. My code works with any combination of separators (colon, space, hyphen).
- The answer assumes you want 4-digit year. To get 3-digit year (stripping first digit):

  - bash: use `${y#?}` instead of `$y`
  - awk: use `substr(a[1],2)` instead of `a[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want `YYYY`:

```
input="YYYY-MM-DD-HH:MM:SS"
awk -F '[:-]' '{print $3 "-" $2 "-" $1 " " $4 ":" $5}' <<<"$input"
```

output

```
DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a real date

```
$ input="2022-06-01-11:10:00"
$ date -d "${input%-*} ${input##*-}" +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'
01-06-2022 11:10
```

GNU awk

```
awk '
   BEGIN{ format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M" }
   {
      gsub(/[-:]/," ");
      print strftime(format, mktime($0))}
' <<<"$input"
01-06-2022 11:10

$ cat file
2022-06-01-11:10:01
2022-07-02-12:11:02
2022-08-03-13:12:03

$ awk 'BEGIN{ format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M" }{gsub(/[-:]/," ");print strftime(format, mktime($0))}' file

01-06-2022 11:10
02-07-2022 12:11
03-08-2022 13:12
```